# Drag the Last Value of a Column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I reviewed all topics and I can't find an answer to this problem I have.

I have four rows from which I have to take data daily for different files and update information. I have the code topy the information but I was wondering how to tell in VBA to go to the column in that row with a value on it... something like this:

```
    Range("CE4").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
```

But then, how can I request that it moves one space to the right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use offset to do this:

```
Range("CE4").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0,1).Select
```

Or more succinctly:

```
Range("CE4").End(xlToRight).Offset(0,1).Select
```

Offset will will move the number of rows and columns, respectively, from the range specified.